# Node 10 - `node-gyp rebuild` error during npm install

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I've recently upgraded to Node 10 and when I run `npm install` I get the following error:

```
make: *** [Release/obj.target/memwatch/src/init.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/david/Documents/gitlab/project/node_modules/memwatch-next
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! memwatch-next@0.3.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the memwatch-next@0.3.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Working on 'macOS Mojave', I worked on the same project with Node10 without any issues.
Please advise what can be causing the error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Resolved the issue by updating npm to latest version & running npm rebuild.

Answer (score 5):

I think delete this directory is better:

```
rm -rf ~/.node-gyp/
rm -r node_modules/.bin/;
rm -r build/
```

and you can test

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

and

```
npm install -g node-pre-gyp
```

finally:

```
npm install <your module>
```

Answer (score 3):

without knowing the actual node-gyp error, make sure you've installed the [node-gyp dependencies](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation) for your platform.

Comment: Added more info, also ran `npm install -g node-gyp` then ran `npm install` got the same error.

Comment: I am having the same problem, also osx mojave.  Also ran npm install -g node-gyp, also got the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Use `NVM` for managing node. It is really helpful. I had the same error but solved it by using the latest **Node LTS** version. That can be done with NVM easily by a single command.

```
nvm install --lts
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend the following:

1. remove node_modules folder
2. `npm install --force`
3. `npm update -g npm --force`
4. If on Windows:
   `npm -g install --production windows-build-tools`
5. run node .js file

Source [GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/711)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue & it was solved by **deleting the yarn.lock** file & then running the `yarn install` again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. First I removed package.json and run npm install but it doesn't help.
Only a return to the previous stable node version helped me. (nvm is very useful)